# Does two text files having same name and content will have same hash (sha256)?

Tags: hash

I am working on a project related to stenography and watermarking. I am using sha256 hash for file authentication purpose. My question is Does two text files having same name and content will have same hash (sha256)? or they will posses different hashes? Kindly help me.

Comment: Yes, and the name doesn't matter. The content does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing exactly this test in php !

```
<?php

$sha11 = sha1_file('C:\Users\rbala\php\progress.php');
$sha12 = sha1_file('C:\Users\rbala\php\tools\progress.php');
$sha13 = sha1_file('C:\Users\rbala\php\tools\progress2.php');

var_dump($sha11, $sha12, $sha13, $sha12 == $sha12, $sha11 == $sha13);

?>
```

This outputs :

```
..\php\php5.2.10\php.exe hashFile.php
string(40) "96e28423aa6ae0f9fa54534eaa152df12deafcea"
string(40) "96e28423aa6ae0f9fa54534eaa152df12deafcea"
string(40) "96e28423aa6ae0f9fa54534eaa152df12deafcea"
bool(true)
bool(true)
```